# Trouble with ScriptControl's Eval method

Tags: windows, asp-classic, vbscript

I got some maintenance tasks on an quite old Classic ASP web application and I'm kinda clueless when it comes to VBScript...

I wonder if it is possible to set the value of a variable using the Eval method of a MSScriptControl.ScriptControl object. Also note that using the AddCode method of ScriptControl before calling Eval() is not an option given the circumstances.
Here is some sample code demonstrating the problem:

```
Dim so,rs,someVar
set someVar=...
set so=server.CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")
so.Language = "VBScript"
so.AllowUI = False
so.AddObject "someVar",someVar

' I get a syntax error here
rs = so.Eval(scrObject.Eval("set someVar = Nothing" & "set someVar = CreateObject("+Chr(34)+"Wscript.Shell"+Chr(34)+")" & "response.write(someVar.CurrentDirectory)"))

' if I try something like this I get a syntax error as well..
rs = so.Eval("Dim someVar2 : someVar2="+Chr(34)+"test"+Chr(34)+" : response.write(someVar2)")
```

I know that Eval method is meant for evaluating expressions, and expressions are not the most reasonable place for declaring or setting the values of variables, but I am wondering if it's still possible somehow.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`eval` and "evil" aren't just similar-sounding. What do you need `eval` for anyway? You should be able to use the code directly:

```
Set someVar = Nothing
Set someVar = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
response.write(someVar.CurrentDirectory)
```

or (even simpler) like this:

```
response.write CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").CurrentDirectory
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's not so simple. Using the ScriptControl seems to be the only way.

Comment: To do *what*? Please describe the problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Besides that your code has illegal assignments, you should start with concatenating strings with the `&` character and not the `+` character:

```
rs = so.Eval(scrObject.Eval("set someVar = Nothing" & "set someVar = CreateObject(" & Chr(34) & "Wscript.Shell" & Chr(34) & ")" & "response.write(someVar.CurrentDirectory)"))
```

But now your output will be a string like:

```
set someVar = Nothingset someVar = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")response.write(someVar.CurrentDirectory)
```

And this is not valid VBScript. You could use linebreaks (`vbNewLine`'s) to separate different lines, but it is easier to use semicolons:

```
rs = so.Eval(scrObject.Eval("set someVar = Nothing : set someVar = CreateObject(" & Chr(34) & "Wscript.Shell" & Chr(34) & ") : response.write(someVar.CurrentDirectory)"))
```

But just like Ansgar Wiecher asks: What are you trying to achieve?